# Extract data from array if IDs match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am struggling to find out a solution to my problem, but at the moment I cannot come up with the right one.

When I have my two arrays of objects I want to filter based on category IDs and extract the data from the second one into a new array for example :

```
    const array1 = [
         {id: 1, name: 'Tropical'},
         {id: 2, name: 'Common'}
]
    
    const array2 = [
         {id:1, name: 'Banana', category_id: 1},
         {id:2, name: 'Mango', category_id: 1},
         {id:3, name: 'Apple', category_id: 2},
    ]
```

And when click happens I detect the first ID and render the new array only with data that matches the ID.
**Click Tropical**
New array :

```
[
 {id:1, name: 'Banana', category_id: 1},
 {id:2, name: 'Mango', category_id: 1},
]
```

I would be happy if someone give me a hint on how can I tackle this problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, So you need a function that received a categoryId and you need to filter out `array2` based on that `category_id`

You can try this

```js
const array1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tropical'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Common'
  }
]

const array2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Banana',
    category_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mango',
    category_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Apple',
    category_id: 2
  },
]

function categoryFruits(categoryId) {
  return array2.filter(obj => obj.id === categoryId)
}

console.log(categoryFruits(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to map over each item in array1 and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to grab the items of that category_id

```js
const array1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tropical'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Common'
  }
]

const array2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Banana',
    category_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mango',
    category_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Apple',
    category_id: 2
  },
]

const obj = array1.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.name] = array2.filter(v => v.category_id === cur.id)
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution i will definitely check it out .

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like filtering `array2` and taking all the elements that have `Tropical` as `name` in `array1`.

```js
const array1 = [
     {id: 1, name: 'Tropical'},
     {id: 2, name: 'Common'}
]

const array2 = [
     {id:1, name: 'Banana', category_id: 1},
     {id:2, name: 'Mango', category_id: 1},
     {id:3, name: 'Apple', category_id: 2},
]

// take tropical friuts
let tropicalFriuts = array2.filter(x => x.category_id === array1.filter(y => y.name === 'Tropical')[0].id);
console.log(tropicalFriuts);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem you want before find the id, based on the name of the category, and later filter array2 data based  on this id.

```js
const array1 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Tropical'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Common'
  }
]

const array2 = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Banana',
    category_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Mango',
    category_id: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Apple',
    category_id: 2
  },
]

const id_key = array1.find(item=>item.name === 'Tropical').id;
const result = array2.filter(item=>item.category_id === id_key);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yes, that's about right. I had almost the same answer but it was not quite right. Thanks for the snippet. I understand it now